# How to achieve Hover effect like this

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I tried to search about this effect in stackover flow, but I have no clue, what developers call this kind of hover effect also no idea to achieve it.

[image: Here is the image with hover and non hover effect:]

Is is possible to achieve this using CSS, if no can i have a solution using jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply add a class called "active" on hover (or "hover"?) and in the CSS, change the background colour of the button part (Quam semper..) to red, and display your overlay (which is a png with a half transparent background and a plus in the middle, and absolute positioning to make sure it's in the top and overlaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this

```
<style type="text/css">
 .thumb {position:relative;width:200px;height:20px;}
.thumb:hover .overlay {opacity:0.5;}
.overlay {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:200px;height:20px;background:#fff;opacity:0;}
</style>

<div class="thumb">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img src="image.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: no problem ... you should mark the answered as accepted if your happy with it ... anything else you need let me know